Matching $f$-number to FOV
I often read that the $f$-number of an optical system (here a camera and a lens) should be matched to the FOV, but doesn't know exactly what it means.
The FOV is determined by the focal length $f$ and the camera sensor diameter $d$. The half FOV $\alpha$ is then (see drawing below, the combination of stop and lens should indicate some idealized camera objective):
$$\alpha = \arctan \left(\frac{d}{2f}\right).$$

The $f$-number is $f_\# = f/D$, with $D$ the aperture diameter that I can adjust by using different $f$-stops. A pixel (on the optical axis) now receives light from a cone of (half) acceptable angle $\beta$ (see drawing above):
$$\beta = \arctan \left(\frac{D}{2f} \right) = \arctan \left(\frac{1}{2f_\#} \right).$$
I'm naively assuming matching would mean to select an $f$-stop or $f$-number so that $\beta$ and $\alpha$ is approximately the same.
Is that correct and if yes, why is it important? What happens if $\beta > \alpha$ (this seems to be of concern when people mention matching is important...)?

Here is a bad sketch of two different lenses with two different focal lengths. Note that the distance you have marked f in your sketch is not the focal length of the lenses in mine. If the distant was f, the rays on the other side would come from an object at infinity. That is, they would be parallel. But you could show that the bottom lens has the shorter focal length.
For both lenses, the sensor and the aperture are the same size. What point in the object plane comes to a focus at the edge of the sensor? You can see how a short focal length or a wide aperture makes that point farther from the optical axis. Or a low f-number makes a big FOV.


Hm, a wide aperture makes the object point farther from the axis (= larger FOV)? I think what determines the FOV is the principal ray (the one from the edge of the sensor through the center of the lens), isn't it? Never heard that the aperture size determines the FOV (makes the image just darker or brighter...?)
